# Как сделать свой заголовок окна ?

Tags: c#

Собственно вопрос в названии. Но в частности интересует как заменить системные кнопки - закрыть, свернуть, развернуть  на свои (картинки).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если разговор про Windows Forms, то я делаю так.

```
this.Text = null;
this.ControlBox = false;
```

После этого на форму кладётся панель с заголовком сверху, перемещение на заголовок панели осуществляется вручную, а все кнопки уже можно добавить куда угодно.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы `300` раз подумал перед тем как сделать то, что вы собираетесь сделать, поскольку вы, судя по всему, планируете:

- Нарушить целую пачку `UX` гайдлайнов и принципов взаимодействия с оконными `Windows` приложениями.
- Получить проблемы совместимости с разными настройками ОС и используемыми темами:

> - Как, например, будут выглядеть ваши кастомные контролы в случае установленной темы `High Contrast`?
> - Планируете ли вы увеличивать их размер при увеличении используемого в системе размера шрифта?
> - А корректно обрабатывать ресайзы окна и `maximize / minimize`?
> - *Если нет, то у меня для вас плохие новости :)*

- Также, наверняка существуют уже имеющиеся и используемые кастомерами приложения, которые опираются на наличие системных кнопок и **не будут работать** или будут вести себя *неожиданно* с вашим приложением.